How to switch between environments in a self-contained .NET 8 app?
I have a .NET 8 app that is self-contained and published, I'm trying to switch between the multiple environments configurations using command line:
c:\path\app.exe --environment Development

but it's not working, it always defaults to Production.
I'm using
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);


This question is similar to: How to set hosting environment name for .NET Core console app using Generic Host (HostBuilder). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Turns out I have to manually set the env variable passed in args, so in Program.cs:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", args[1]);
and after that you read it elsewhere by:
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")
The args are passed like this: exename.exe --environment Production
